# Objective-C Block which accepts an object and returns a boolean

Tags: objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks

Can you please write for me a block which conforms to this definition: `(BOOL(^)(id))block`.

The closest I have gotten is:

```
typedef BOOL (^birds)(MyObject*);
birds c = ^(MyObject* p){ return (BOOL)[p.something boolValue]; };
```

But it seems passing this `c` in a message who wants `(BOOL(^)(id))block` is a no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a Block `BOOL (^block)(id)` is expected you need to pass such a block and not a `BOOL (^block)(MyObject *)`.

So try this:

```
typedef BOOL (^birds)(id);
birds c = ^(id pp) { MyObject *p = (MyObject *) pp; return [p.something boolValue]; };
```

Comment: Can you edit to add the semicolon to the end of the line? It tripped me up so it'll probably trip someone else.

Comment: why not typedef BOOL(^birds)(*MyObject); ?